# Is there a way to hardcode "response" in @ApiResponse annotation of swagger?

Tags: json, api, dns, annotations, swagger

I've the below Swagger annotation for one of my api methods:

```
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = String.class)
```

Is there a way I can hard-code the `response` ?

I'm **NOT** keeping any domain objects in my service; my service is a kind-of wrapper service that connects with a third party vendor service and returns the json as-it-is to the caller.
So, is there a way I can hardcode the json schema in the `response` element ?

I know that if I define a domain object and mention its `.class`, I'll get the json schema in the output but as I mentioned I need to find a way **without** defining a domain object.

Also providing the hardocded json schema in `message` attribute will not make sense as because, I believe, this attribute is more for *describing* the status `code`, correct ?

Thanks to provide any pointers/suggestions.

Comment: appreciate if someone can respond pls !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got few suggestions on other forum.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1574